# Why Pushout in Set are not simple unions?

Tags: category-theory, pullback

Why do we use disjoint unions instead of simple unions to have **pushout** in Set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Because the pushout must have a certain universal property, and the non-disjoint union does not have this property.

Comment: Could you provide an example in which union fails to have the universal property? I could not find in literature and I could not produce an example which shows the failure.

Comment: @RegivanHugoNunesSantiago By the uniqueness of pushouts, any union that doesn’t coincide with the pushout will work. For instance $\{1\}\cup\{1\}$ lacks the universal property of the pushout of $\{1\}\leftarrow\{\}\to\{1\}.$ (Consider any cocone doing different things to the two copies of $1$.)

Comment: Dear @kevinArlin thank you very much.